# How to play sound and stop sound using combobox[AS3]?

Tags: actionscript-3

In this code, all sounds play together.

I want when sound1 is playing, sound2 to stop. When sound2 starts to play, sound1 to stop.

```
stop();

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.Sound;



var mysound1:MYSf = new MYSf
var mysound2:sounda = new sounda

combobox.addItem( { label: "sound1" } );
combobox.addItem( { label: "sound2" } );


combobox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, myq);

function myq (e:Event):void
{
    if (combobox.selectedItem.label == "sound1")
    {
        mysound1.play();
        mysound2.stop();
    }
    if (combobox.selectedItem.label == "sound2")
    {
        mysound2.play();
        mysound1.stop();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this following code?

```
function myq (e:Event):void
{
    mysound1.stop();
    mysound2.stop();
    if (combobox.selectedItem.label == "sound1")
    {
        mysound1.play();

    }
    if (combobox.selectedItem.label == "sound2")
    {
        mysound2.play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop a sound playing using the `Sound` class. The `Sound` class does not have a `stop` method. Instead you need to use a `SoundChannel` class to stop a sound playing.

From the Adobe API document ([here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html)):

> the sound object must be assigned to a SoundChannel object in order to use the SoundChannel's `stop()` method to pause the sound.